# The size of void

Tags: c, pointers

If I would want to operate on pointers which point to one byte should I use void* or char*, because I heard that

```
sizeof(char)
```

isn't always 1 byte, and what about void*? If I do

```
void *p
++p
```

will it point everywhere one byte further?

Comment: Where did you hear that a char isn't one byte in size? Tell them they were wrong.

Comment: @MrLister: many confuse C bytes with 8-bit bytes. They don't have to be the same thing.

Comment: Just so we're in the clear, neither the OP nor me mentioned 8 bits! A char is a byte. If you increment a char pointer, it points to the next byte. If you increment a void pointer, you get nasal demons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C **pointer arithmetic is not defined for void pointers**. Pointer arithmetic is intrinsically tied to the size of the pointed type. And for `void *` the size of the pointed type is unknown.

To see how pointer arithmetic works for different objects, try this:

```
int obj[5];
int *ip = obj;
char *cp = (char *)obj;

ip++;
cp++;

printf("%p\n%p\n", ip, cp);
```

However, if the compiler does support it, pointer arithmetic on void pointers works the same as on char pointers.

Comment: That is the interesting thing, in GCC it is defined but I read that is only some GCC extension, and what about sizeof(char), is it always 1 byte? I just need to have pointer that after incrementing will be 1 byte further, and possibly this behaviour should be platform independent.

Comment: @Andna Yes, `sizeof(char)` is by definition 1.

Comment: @Andna: The size of none of the types is defined as such(exception is `char` which is defined as `1`, **C99-6.5.3.4**).Generally you should not assume size of types to be something specific & that is the purpose that `sizeof` exists & you should use it. It is well defined that If you have an array of particular type and a pointer pointing to it then incrementing the pointer will make it point to the next element in the array.ofcourse, it does not apply to `void` pointers.

Answer (score 1):

For this, I think you should use `<stdint.h>`. It defines the following types (among others):

```
uint8_t   Always 1 byte (assuming 8-bit bytes, as is nearly ubiquitous)
uint16_t  Always 2 bytes
uint32_t  Always 4 bytes
uint64_t  Always 8 bytes
```

If you know what you're doing, and want to pointer-arithmetic your way around memory, then do it with a `uint8_t*` pointer.  (Yes I just used that as a verb, BTW.)

Example:

```
uint8_t* p = <Some Base Addr>;
while (*p)   // p points to non-null byte
{
    *p ^= 0xA5;   // XOR the byte with A5
    p++;          // Increment to the next byte.

    *(uint32_t*)p = 0xDEADBEEF;  // Write a 32-bit (DWORD)
    ((uint32_t*)p)++;            // Increment p by 4 bytes
}
```

Comment: These are 8-bit bytes, not C bytes.

Comment: your example has issues: it violates strict aliasing and will actually raise an exception on architectures which don't access mis-aligned memory

Comment: @Christoph While my example *does* access mis-aligned memory, I don't believe it violates strict aliasing, as any type can alias `char` (and `uint8_t` is almost certainly typedef'd to `unsigned char`).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: according to the standard C effective typing semantics, it's the memory itself that is typed, no matter the pointer used to access it, ie `*(uint32_t*)p` is only legal if the memory location pointed-to by `p` has been declared explicitly as `uint32_t` or compatible (ie `int32_t` or a union containing such a member) or implicitly so through storage in case of dynamic allocation; `*(uint32_t*)p` combined with `*(uint32_t*)(p+1)` can only not violate these rules if it points to something like `union { struct { uint32_t u1; char c1 }; struct { char c2; uint32_t u2; };  }`

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a `char` takes a single byte of storage, so if you want to do address calculations based on byte sizes, use `char *`. While the C standard requires `void *` to have the same representation as `char *`, `void *` carries no size information and thus can't be used for pointer arithmetics.

If you actually want to get at the bits of an object's representation, use `unsigned char` as `char` might be signed and is not specified to be padding-free.

Now, a comment on [Jonathon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9850224/48015):

While the fixed-width integer types from `stdint.h` are also padding-free and you can use them as decribed on specific architectures (there's nothing wrong with platform-specific code if you don't need to be protable), in general you only know their bit-widths, not their byte sizes as `CHAR_BIT` can be different from 8 (16 and 32 are 'common' for some parts of the embedded world). However, byte == octet is required for POSIX systems.

Fixed-width integer types of specific sizes don't need to exist: In particular, if `CHAR_BIT` isn't a power of 2 (yes, such architectures exist), none of the types `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, `uint64_t` *can* exist